# Lorentz boost in light-cone coordinates

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, momentum, coordinate-systems, lorentz-symmetry

Consider a particle with momentum $p^{\mu}=(p^+,p^-,p_{\perp})$, where the momentum is written in light cone coordinates defined as, 
\begin{align}
n^{\mu}&=(1,0,0,1)& \bar{n}^{\mu}=(1,0,0,-1)
\end{align}
and $p^+\equiv n.p$ and $p^-\equiv \bar{n}.p$. I am not able to understand how the light cone coordinated transform under Lorentz transformation. If the particle is boosted along $-z$ direction by amount $\kappa$, then $p^-\to \kappa p^-$ and $p^+\to p^+/\kappa$. This is basically equation 2.9 of [link](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-851-effective-field-theory-spring-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_851S13_scetnotes.pdf).

Please explain or share useful link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the usual coordinate system where $p_t^2-(p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2)$ is Lorentz invariant, a boost in the $t$-$z$ plane is
\begin{gather}
 p_t\to p_t\cosh\theta+p_z\sinh\theta
\\
 p_z\to p_z\cosh\theta+p_t\sinh\theta
\end{gather}
with
$$
 \cosh^2\theta-\sinh^2\theta = 1.
$$
In light-cone coordinates with $p_\pm = p_t\pm p_z$, this implies
\begin{align}
 p_+&\to (\cosh\theta+\sinh\theta)p_+ = \kappa p_+
\\
 p_-&\to (\cosh\theta-\sinh\theta)p_- = (1/\kappa) p_-
\end{align}
with $\kappa=e^\theta$. This follows from the definitions of $\cosh\theta$ and $\sinh\theta$, namely
$$
 \cosh\theta=\frac{e^\theta+e^{-\theta}}{2}
\hskip2cm
 \sinh\theta=\frac{e^\theta-e^{-\theta}}{2}.
$$