# What is an easy way to identify the generator of a matrix (Lie) Group?

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra, linear-algebra

I am trying to figure out an easy way to identify the generator of the following matrix group:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
e^{x} & 0 & a \\
0 & e^{-x} & a' \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

In this case this is the Poincare group but I was wondering what is a "non-formal" way to find a basis and hence the structure constants of a lie algebra?

Comment: Working near the identity, x=0=a=a' , you already have your basis:  your group element is  +(_3,0)++′, where A is the matrix with 1 in the 31 entry, and B with 1 in the 32 entry, and 0 elsewhere. You are *already* there.

Comment: @CosmasZachos is σ_3 the pauli matrix?

Comment: Of course it is; in the upper 2x2 block, the 33 entry outside of which is 0.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/495509/lorentz-boost-in-light-cone-coordinates).

Comment: The group element acts on light cone coordinates,  $(x+t,x-t,1)^T$. You are already there.
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
e^{z} & 0 & a \\
0 & e^{-z} & a' \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  = I + z   \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0    \\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}    + a  \begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 1    \\
0 & 0& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}   + a'  \begin{bmatrix}
 0& 0 & 0    \\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}   + O(z^2) + O(a^2) +O(a'^2).$$
These three generators, $M, P_+,P_-$ are your basis.

Comment: Actually, there manifestly aren't any terms higher than linear in *a* and *a'*...

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much for your responses.

Comment: I stuck the comment into an answer, now that the question is open.

Answer (score 1):

Easy. The group element acts on light cone coordinates,  $(x+t,x-t,1)^T$. You are already there.
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
e^{z} & 0 & a \\
0 & e^{-z} & a' \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  = I + z   \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0    \\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}    + a  \begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 1    \\
0 & 0& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}   + a'  \begin{bmatrix}
 0& 0 & 0    \\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}   + O(z^2)  ~.$$
These three generators, $M, P_+,P_-$, are your Lie algebra basis.
That is, the generic Lie algebra 3-vector is $zM+aP_++ a'P_-$.